# Alternative multi-threading optimization languages that run on JVM besides Scala?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, jvm, scalacl

I am looking for alternatives or competitors to Scala strictly in regards to programming desktop apps on multiple cores. Whether using CPU or GPU cores (ScalaCL), I want to take advantage of all possible multi-threading performance. Scala is definitely a good choice, but I want to know what other options I can pursue. Running on the JVM is key for what I need.

Comment: you've dismissed java? if that's the case, I'm curious what is it about scala that you'd prefer over vanilla java (with regards to multi-core utilisation)

Comment: I believe that anything that can be done in Scala is doable in Java, but Scala makes it much simpler to multi-thread. That is what I am looking for, features that simplify multi-threading. I believe Scala has lots of features to say for example, take a for loop and make it run on as many threads as possible.

Comment: Desktop apps mulyicores. That sounds vague. Can you specify your problem further? Have you looked at actors and at STM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clojure is a JVM language designed for concurrency, see: http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming

Answer (score 3):

You could always use Java with one of the "concurrency" libraries that provide Actor frameworks, STM etc. One that springs to mind is akka (http://akka.io/).

There's also the jCUDA http://www.jcuda.org/ library which *might* help with your requirement for GPU processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you like Groovy, you can also check out GPars, which offers Actors as well as Dataflow models.

http://gpars.codehaus.org/